# How do I add margin above images in Bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I make the browser window small, the images are clumped together, I want to add some spacing between them, when they stack vertically, note that I also want to do this in pure bootstrap, because I know how to do it in css.

Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250">
      </div>
```

Comment: With media query add margin, specif for devices you want to add margin.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   img { 
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
   }
}
```

You can use it with media query to control every element in different screens.

Thia code control the extra small screen like mobile screen.. it will add margin bottom to every image.

Follow the link to know more about media query
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon in SO. Please add some explanation for the benefit of others reading your code!